# Android doesn't rotate automatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I created an alternate layout in Eclipse

```
res/layout-land/main.xml
```

I am using Hello Android 3rd Edition to learn Android.

Am I missing anything?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.oneorangetree.sudoku"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Sodoku"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/about_title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">            
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What exactly is happening? Are u testing on phone or emulator?

Comment: Make sure you don't have something like `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I checked my Manifest and there isn't anything that says "android:screenOrientation" there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a setting "auto-rotate" in setting "display" on the device. Check that it's activated.

Comment: Are you referring to a device setting? Other apps rotate fine. (Google Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

See the possible options here
[CLICK HERE](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping)